# Passing Data using transition for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, cosmicmind, prepareforreuse

I am trying to implement something like the Photo View Collection using Cosmic Mind's Material framework in Swift 4.1.

In traditional segue, I can do something like this to pass data from 1 VC to another,

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "nextVC" {
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! NextViewController
            destinationVC.scoreInt = score
            destinationVC.dataSource = list
        }
    }
```

The only line of code in charge of swapping view controllers I see is this,

```
toolbarController?.transition(to: PhotoViewController(index: indexPath.item))
```

How can I pass data same as prepare for segue. Is there any delegate method to implement to get that functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the segue you are getting an instance of your view controller and then setting properties. You can do exactly that in the sample line, actually the `index` parameter is doing that in the constructor. You would only need to prepare and pass the data before you call the `transition` method. Once the data is passed, then you can pass the view controller to the `transition` method, and the data is then available to that controller.